# Stata: adding coefficients to estout

Tags: stata

I want to output the results of several regressions as a nicely formatted LaTeX table and am happy to see that for most cases the `estout` package on SSC seems to do exactly that.

However, what I want is a bit special: Between the table section that shows the coefficient estimates and their standard errors, and the section that shows R^2 and the like, I would like to add a section that shows point estimates and standard errors (bonus points for stars) for particular linear combinations of the coefficients. Both point estimates and standard errors are easily computed via `lincom` but the best solution I've found so far for getting these numbers into the table involves the massily hacky addition of these numbers, one `estadd scalar ...` at a time. Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Example code:

```
sysuse auto
eststo, title("Model 1"): regress price weight mpg
lincom weight+mpg
estadd scalar skal r(estimate)
estadd scalar skalsd r(se)
eststo, title("Model 2"): regress price weight mpg foreign
lincom weight+mpg
estadd scalar skal r(estimate)
estadd scalar skalsd r(se)
label variable foreign "Car type (1=foreign)"
estout, cells(b(star fmt(3)) t(par fmt(2)))  ///
     stats(skal skalsd r2 N, labels("Linear Combination" "S.E." R-squared "N. of cases")) ///
     label legend varlabels(_cons Constant)
```

Comment: Elsewhere (Statalist) explaining  which programs referred to are user-written and where they come from is strongly recommended as good practice. There is no such rule on SO, but I'd like to encourage that practice here as informative. So, `estout` is from SSC. (I don't use it, so I stop here.)

Comment: Yes, estout is user-written. But since it's hardly an obscure package I thought I'd take a chance. I've already scoured Stateline as well as the rest of the interwebs for an answer but have, unfortunately, come up empty.

Comment: Wrong way to think about it, in my view. The purpose of this forum is not just to get  answers to individuals' questions, but to provide an archive for all, so informative detail almost never hurts and can be ignored by those to whom it is superfluous. By "Stateline" I guess you mean "Statalist". Still true that there are more users on Statalist experienced with `estout` than there are here, I guess.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect the fact that estout is from SSC.

Comment: you can also flag to migrate [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) incase

Comment: @Metrics Thanks, but this seems to me to be a question that's primarily about a Stata package and not LaTeX. I know how to do all of this by hand but I'd rather Stata do it for me so whatever I produce is reproducible by others.

Comment: There is an example on `lincom` in help file of user function `outreg2` but it uses `local` instead of `estadd scalar`. In terms of efficiency, I think there is no gain.

Comment: Probably true, but thank you anyway. Perhaps I should just stick with what I've got then. Any way I could round the standard error to two decimals and wrap it in parentheses before writing it to the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `layout`, `star` and `fmt` sub-options to format the added scalars like this:

```
estout, cells(b(star fmt(3)) t(par fmt(2)))  ///
     stats(skal skalsd r2 N, layout(@ (@) @ @) star(skal) labels("Linear Combination" "S.E." R-squared "N. of cases") fmt(%9.2f %9.2f %9.2f %12.0f)) ///
     label legend varlabels(_cons Constant)
```

These options are documented [here](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_estout.html#stats). As far as I know, the method in your question is the only way to do this.

Comment: Now I'm embarrassed that I didn't find this earlier. Thank you _very_ much for your patience with a newbie like me!

Comment: No worries. I love this command and use it every day, but matching what you want with `estout` documentation can be a bit tricky.

Comment: Note that `star(skal)` does not attach significance stars to the `skal` coefficient by using the standard error.  It might show stars even if `skal` is not significant!

Answer (score 2):

There's a problem with the answer above. I think the original poster wanted statistical significance stars based on a test of the `lincom` (weight+mpg) vs zero. That is not what `star(skal)` does.

As the [documentation](http://repec.org/bocode/e/estout/hlp_estout.html#stats) states: `star[(`*scalarlist*`)]` to specify that the **overall significance** of the model be denoted by stars. The stars are attached to the scalar statistics specified in *scalarlist*." Emphasis mine.

`star(skal)` in the previous example will place significance stars next to the estimates of `skal`, but they will be from an F-test of the overall significance of the regression model (I think). Not from `lincom`.

When I use this strategy on other specifications, the stars attached are clearly not based on the ones from `lincom`. I'm not sure if it's possible to use `lincom`/`esttab` to get the stars from `lincom`. To say nothing of `nlcom`!

Comment: A similar point was made in an answer, now deleted, on Nov 25 2014. I don't use these excellent commands but I hope this doesn't get deleted. It's better here as an "answer" than as comments.